# Trouble Assigning Values to PHP Array using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I'm having some trouble with a PHP array that, so far as I can tell, should be working.  I'm working with simpleXML and looping over a simpleXML output.  I'm then trying to take the 'id' attribute off the relevant XML node, assign that as the key of a new item in an array, and assign the value as the country name.  Here's a sample of my simpleXML output (`$cxml` in the code below):

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
  [country] => Array ( 
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
      [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => AD ) 
      [name] => ANDORRA 
      [ssc] => EUR 
    ) 
    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
      [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => AE ) 
      [name] => UNITED ARAB EMIRATES 
      [ssc] => EUR 
    ) 
    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
      [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => AF ) 
      [name] => AFGHANISTAN 
      [ssc] => ASI 
    ) ...
  )
```

and so forth.  Here's my code:

```
function generateCountryList() {
  global $server_path;
  // the following line generates - correctly - the object I gave above
  $cxml = simplexml_load_file($server_path . 'countries/');  
  $c = array();
  foreach ($cxml->country as $cntry => $rec) {
    $rid = $rec['id'];
    $rname = ucwords(strtolower($rec->name));
    //the following echo statements are for debugging only
    echo $rid;  //returns the country ID; for example, AD on the 0th element in the object
    echo $rname;  //returns the country name; for example, Andorra on the 0th element in the object
    $c[$rid] = $rname;  //the goal here is to have an array of the form    
                        //['AD'=>'Andorra','AE'=>'United Arab Emirates',...]
 }
return $c;
}
```

If I return `$c` and assign it to a variable, then `print_r` that variable, I get an empty array.  I get the same thing if I run `print_r($c);` within this function.

I'd appreciate any help someone can offer on why I'm not able to build this array!

Comment: I just figured this out moments before I posted the question, but I'm still stuck with another question, and I thought this might be helpful to others.

The trick lay in specifying that $rec['id'] was a string.  Replacing the relevant line with `$rid = (string)$rec['id'];` fixed the problem straight away.

Since I'm here already, I'd love some help understanding why this is necessary.  The data is clearly a string, so why does it choke when I don't specify it?

Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

When you navigate to a child node of a SimpleXML object using `$element->elementName`, what you get is another SimpleXML object, so that you can carry on navigating from there. To get the string content of the child node, you use the PHP string cast operator: `(string)$element->elementName`.

What's less obvious is that when you navigate to an **attribute**, using `$element['attribName']`, that **also** gives you another SimpleXML object. There aren't many things you'd want with that object other than the string contents, but you might want to call `$attrib->getName()` inside a loop, for instance. So again, to get the string contents, you have to use `(string)$element['attribName']`, as you discovered.

Now, some functions and constructs in PHP, such as `echo` **implicitly cast to string**, because there is simply no other data type to use with them. However, rather than learning exactly which these are, and adding confusion when changing your code, my recommendation is to **always cast any SimpleXML result to string explicitly with `(string)`**.

One final note: you can also get an integer value from the contents using `(int)`, and a float using `(float)`. However, using the object in a sum, such as `$element['attribName'] * 1.0` will always convert it to an integer, whatever values are involved. Again, explicit casts will lead to fewer surprises.